# how to add distance between daysOfWeek and date #table_calendar: ^3.0.6

Tags: flutter

what I expected:

[image]

reality:

[image]

the difference, the distance between daysOfWeek and date

> mycode : where can i add padding?

```
        daysOfWeekStyle: const DaysOfWeekStyle(
            weekdayStyle: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'SF-Pro',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              color: Color(0XFF8F9BB3),
              fontSize: 13,
            ),
        weekendStyle: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'SF-Pro',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          color: Color(0XFF8F9BB3),
          fontSize: 13,
        ),
      ),

      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: secondaryColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
        defaultDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: whiteColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: add some pading

Comment: where can i add padding? @MrShakila

Comment: update your code to the question

Comment: I have changed @MrShakila

Comment: wrap your DaysOfWeekStyle using padding widget

Comment: where can i change it? @MrShakila

Comment: I've got the answer. add one parameter in Table Calendar
// days Of Week Height: 30,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've got the answer. add one parameter in Table Calendar // days Of Week Height: 30,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).